# Problems with small signals through BNC connectors?

Tags: connector, coax, bnc

I have a 120kHz signal from a transducer with peak to peak values of typically 40mV being carried over coax cable and connected at both ends via BNC connectors. Most of the time this seems to work, however there do appear to be occasional signal quality problems. Is there likely to be a problem with such small signals though this arrangement?

By "signal quality" I mean distortion of the sine wave and/or added noise related to the twisting of the cable. I am guessing that this may be related to the connector pin rotating and causing changing conductivity at the contact points

Comment: Signal quality problems???

Comment: @DirkBruere:  50 ohm cables with BNC connectors are routinely used to carry microvolt level RF signals.  There shouldn't be any inherent problem in using BNC connectors for your task.  Bad connectors or cables could be a problem, though.

Comment: What is "signal quality?"  Lost signal (attenuation?) Distorted signal?  Interference?

Comment: Edited to clarify signal quality

Comment: @JRE It may be that RF signals can capacitively couple across (say) oxide layers on metal contacts, whereas my low frequency stuff might not

Comment: What is the transducer - please supply data sheet link? What sort of environment are you in? Gases? Tarnishing effects due to gases?

Comment: @Andyaka It's an ultrasonic transducer. So fixed frequency, varying amplitude sinusoidal ping

Comment: I have met microphonic cable. That cable generated substantial noise when it was bent or pressed. A piezoelectric sensor nor high Z amplifier input  didn't suppress the noise.  Low impedance systems had no trouble with the same cable. Test the cable with the same sensor and amp but without the BNC connectors to find the quilty.

Comment: @user287001 Yes. I need to do some serious and extensive and time consuming testing. What works in the lab does not always work at a customers site

Comment: If you are twisting the connectors on an ongoing basis, nevermind the electric concerns, you have a mechanical wear problem which you probably need to fix by better physical layout.

Answer (score 2):

While there are many possible sources of noise in your setup, you've found it's associated with "twisting of the cable" and have suggested it's related to the connector pin rotating.

That's possible, but you should also consider "triboelectric noise" as well. This is a well-known source of noise in medical instrumentation cables carrying low-level signals (EEG, EKG, etc). It's basically caused by static electricity being generated as the conductors rub against the dielectric insulation.

You need to do a differential diagnosis. If the noise is worst when you "do the twist" near the connector, your hypothesis is probably right. But if there's noise when you clamp the cable a few inches from the connector and "do the twist" on the free portion, then it's probably triboelectric. Look into higher quality low-noise cables designed for medical instrumentation. Good luck!